# Как решить проблему с InputSimulator для клавиши F5 на C#?

Tags: c#

Есть следующий код:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_F5);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
```

Со второй строчкой никаких проблем, если оставить только её, то все хорошо выполняется. Но на первую компилятор жалуется, говорит мол не существует VK_F5, каким образом можно решить данную проблему? Благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Как вариант - Найдите "c# VirtualKeyCode" например тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx и поставьте напрямую 0x74 (VK_F5). Может библиотека не та?

Comment: Я пробовал напрямую, может не правильно сделал просто: InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.0x74);
Библиотека: using WindowsInput;

Comment: Нет, или так `InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(0x74)` если ругается то так `InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress((WORD)0x74)` не работал с этой библиотекой. Если не работает - отпишитесь другие подскажут.

Comment: В обоих случаях не работает. В первом: cannot convert from 'int' to 
'WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode'
Во втором не находит WORD

Comment: вот тут есть что-то похожее http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp

Comment: Тогда попробуйте кастить к WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode  `InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress((WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode)0x74)`

Comment: Решил проблему тем, что вместо VK_F5 нужно писать просто F5, хотя в мане написано что VK_F5 вроде, странно. В любом случае спасибо всем за помощь.